# useContext returns undefined (React Native, Expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, use-context

I am trying to retrieve user data(name, email) to display after I login but I keep getting `undefined` but whenever I `console.log( user )` I see all the data including the name and email

**Context.js**

```
import React  from 'react';
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
export default AuthContext;
```

**App.js**

```
import AuthContext from './context';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
          { user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator/> }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**Panel.js**

```
const Panel = ({navigation}) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Name {user.name} </Text>
      <Text>Email {user.email} </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Login.js**

```
const handleSubmit = async ( { email, password } ) =>{
    const response = await axios.post(userLogin, 
    { 
        email, 
        password,
    })
    .then((response) => { 
        const user = response.data;
        authContext.setUser(user);
        // console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => { 
        console.log(error);
    }); 
}
```

**console.log(user) result**

```
Object {
  "token": "27|YUHmPPwmRkgQRFkAmbEpSjweXN6QI8eR7O1bHhfd",
  "user": Object {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "maria",
    "email": "maria@mail.com",
    "user_type": "vendor",
    "vendor_address": "55 bola way road",
    "vendor_fullname": "maria smith",
  },
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Mabye the user is initially undefined and you need to add the "?" in front of name and email like so: user?.name user?.email

Comment: Hi, thank for your response, I change it to `{user?.name}` and `{user?.email}` but I am still getting `undefined`

Comment: Please edit your post to show where you console.log the user and what the console.log looks like

Comment: @delle where in your code do you actually set a user? Here `const [user, setUser] = useState();` you initialize it as `undefined`, and I don't see that you ever change that.

Comment: @MaximilianDietel I have edit my code, u can check the console.log result above

Comment: @Thomas set it in login.js and as a variable in App.js see the above edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be because at first render user is undefined, so you can't access email and name you can use user?.user.?name like so for email.
to validate what I'm saying try giving a static user in The App.js you will see that the error is gone

Comment: Hi @Zein thank for your response, I change it to `{user?.name}` and `{user?.email}` but I am still gettng `undefined`

Comment: user?.user?.name